# SQL Server set to force encryption, SSMS says it's not

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I've set my MS SQL Server instance to Force encryption:[image: force encryption]

I've saved this setting and restarted SQL Server (and thus SQL Server Agent).

However, when I connect to this server with SQL Server Management Studio, I see two things.

First, this query says my connection is encrypted (found the query on the internet):

```
USE master
GO
SELECT encrypt_option FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
GO
```

But when I look into the Properties dialog of SSMS, it says the connection is not encrypted:[image: not-encrypted]

So which is it? Have I correctly forced encryption? I must add that this is using a self-signed certificate (ie, just set the flag to Yes).

**Update:** funnily enough, I did it on another server and there the Properties panel does say it's encrypted.

**Update 2:**

In both cases, I'm using SSMS 2016 (13.0.16106.4) on my local machine, making a call to the other server.

The `@@version` for the one that says it's encrypted is `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64)   Oct 20 2015 15:36:27   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`.

For the one where the panel says it's not encrypted, I get `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5343.0 (X64)   May  4 2015 19:11:32   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`.

I see the "working" one has a service pack applied?